# Page Load for extracting from Google chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have found a few related questions, but none was able to solve my problem, so any help is greatly appreciated!

I am fairly new to coding and am creating a JavaScript extractor for the chrome console. I am loading a search page, but when Javascript attempts to extract the information, the search is not loaded yet.

I tried a for loop to pause my script, but turns out the page load is paused during that time. I found something like this:

```
for(var i=0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
    setTimeout(function(i) {
        return function() { dosomethingheavy(i); }
    }(i), 0);
}
```

but it did not work right (or I did not know how to use it properly). I structured my code like this:

For loop to go to each page, extract info from page, go to next page, in the end it returns a csv file of all the data.

My question is how can I allow for the ca. 2 sec page load?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You must wait for the DOM to be fully loaded before acting. You can do that using the `DOMContentLoaded` event.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    dosomethingheavy();
}, false);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! So just to clarify - I found the dosomethingheavy() in another post, and I am not sure what it is. Is that my extraction function?